# Alamofire 5 POST method having array parameters usage with swift 5

Tags: spring-boot, alamofire, swift5, xcode11, alamofire-request

I am working on an iOS project with Swift 5 with Almofire 5.0.2. I tried all the options suggested on an online thread similar to this but it looks like I am still missing something.

I am facing difficulty in during a POST method API call with an array of items as apart of the request body.

API looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
SomeResponse doSomething (@RequestBody SomeRequest request) {}
```

I am using Swift 5 and alamo fire 5.0.2 version and I tried above option along with below option but it didn't hit API at all( returns AFError):

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "block": true,
            "items": [],
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "mobile": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
            "List": [["place": "london"],["place": "holand"]]

  ]

AF.request(BookingConstants.httpEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseData { response in

}
```

I am getting this error on java spring boot API side :

```
Invalid index in property path 'item[][place]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""] with root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:663) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHoldingValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:402) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processKeyedProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:859) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:755) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:192) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE
```

I know I am missing something but couldn't figure it out. Can someone please help me out with this? Please let me know your comments/suggestions if any. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post the error you're getting.

Comment: @JonShier Thanks ! i have updated logs

Comment: I meant the client error. But it sounds like you're sending bad data, so the server is likely responding with a 500 error which doesn't contain JSON.

Comment: @JonShier: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. There is no error on the client-side as it is a bad request and as u said I am not sending the data in the right format. That is where I am stuck what is the right way to send this kind of data from iOS client. Maybe i have to switch to some other alternative of almofire.

Comment: I'm not sure why an alternative would help if you don't know what your parameters are supposed to look like. What kind of parameter encoding does the server expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to Alamofire 4.0.1 version and used the Alamofire upload method to achieve this.

```
let objectAsJSON: JSON = request.toJSON()
let data: Data = try objectAsJSON.serialize()

Alamofire.upload(data, to: BookingConstants.httpEndpoint, headers: headers)
                .validate()
                .responseData { response in
        // response code logic

}
```